How to generate animations automatically in Live Editor
I am using MATLAB R2024a,editing in live editor, and update a plot in while loop, how to animate the update progress automatically?
Here is my sample code, updating a plot in the while loop.
When n is set to >=9, the output window automatically generate an animation and control bar that can preview the progress and export the animation, however, when n is < 8, The output result is just a figure. Is there anyway to generate the animation all the time, even if n is small?
% creating the date
clear;
x=randi(100,10);
y=randi(100,10);
scatter(x,y,"black");

%set loop times
n=9

while n>0
    plotnodes(x(n),y(n));

    %wait for user's input
    input("Press any key to continue");
    n=n-1;

end


% plot function
function plotnodes(x,y)
hold on;
plot(x,y,'ro',"MarkerSize",10,"LineWidth",2)
hold off;
end

n=9, generating control bar and animation automatically,
n =9
n=8, just a static figure
enter image description here

You can try adding drawnow to force the update of the figure.
Also consider that when input is called with only the prompt as parameter, it expect from the user an expression to be evaluated or a digit.
If you are not interested to the specific input provided by the user, you can add "s" as second input parameter; this will prevent input evaluating the user input as an expression.
As an alternative to input you can use pause to stop MATLAB execution temporarily
This is the updated code
% creating the date
clear;
x=randi(100,10);
y=randi(100,10);
scatter(x,y,"black");

%set loop times
n=9;

while n>0
    plotnodes(x(n),y(n));
    %
    % Add drawnow to upated the plot
    %
    drawnow
    %wait for user's input
    %
    % Add "s" to treat the input as test without evaluatng the expression
    %
    input("Press any key to continue","s");
    n=n-1;

end


% plot function

function plotnodes(x,y)
hold on;
plot(x,y,'ro',"MarkerSize",10,"LineWidth",2)
hold off;
end


Thank you for your suggestion about using "pause", it is better than using input. However, it's not the problem about animation does not update automatically, It is about after the program finished, the "live editor" generates different results when n is different: when n <= 8, the result is just an static pic, when n>=9, the result is a interactable animation, you can check the different results from the picture link at the bottom of the question.
